# How to retrieve image file paths from mysql database and display the images using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I'm trying to retrieve an image file path from mysql database using php and display it to a form that will then be used to send the images to our android app. I have search around everywhere and i found one that looks like my problem but it has not been solved so I'm trying to find another help.

here is my php form for uploading images:
inSTAGram.php

```
<?php

require('admin.config.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$path = "/home/stagcon2/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";

if($image_name==''){
echo "Don't just click! select an image please .";
exit();
}
else{
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $path);
$mysql_path = $path."/".$image_name;
$query = "INSERT INTO `inSTAGram`(`image_name`,`path`) VALUES ('$image_name','$mysql_path')";

$query_params = array(
    ':image_name' => $image_name,
    ':mysql_path' => $path,
    );

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't Upload Image!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Image Uploaded Succesfully!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
}   
?>

<form action="inSTAGram.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" >
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" >
</form>
```

this one works just right!

so here is my php form for the displaying of image;
inSTAGramDisplay.php

```
<?php
require("admin.config.inc.php");

//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM inSTAGram";

try {
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error!";
die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Image Available!";
$response["images"]   = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $rows             = array();
    $rows['image'] = 'http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/pictures?image_id=' . $rows['image_id'];
    $rows[] = $rows;        

    //update our repsonse JSON data
    array_push($response["images"], $image);
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($rows);


} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Image Available!";
die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

this time, this one shows the image path and not the image, what i wanted to do is display the images itself. I just don't have any idea what the right thing to do here. any help will do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo an image tag and put the image variable as it source attribute:

```
<?php
//I hard coded the array but pull the images id from the db
$rows  = array();
$rows = array("070415togepi.jpg",
              "1384904_681730675185076_523601772_n.jpg",
              "1388517_681730668518410_508160046_n.jpg",
              "1394889_681730678518409_1155435015_n.jpg", 
              "385-jirachi-g.jpg"); 

foreach ($rows as $value){
 $rows['img'] = 'http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/pictures/'.$value;
 echo "<img src='".$rows['img']."' />";
}

?>
```

Comment: hi! I just did what you have said above and you exactly got out the data from the database. If I'm not mistaken, for larger amount of images you have to store it on a file system and store the path inside the db so that's what I did. please correct me if I'm wrong. The problem in your suggestion is that, it displayed the path itself and not the images. any other suggestions or help?

Comment: thanks! that did the trick. but i just want to ask you, the data inserted to the database will be from the user and that means that the images will keeps on adding up. i was wondering if i need to code all the image file name to the array so that it will work?

Comment: @IamMe. Yes when retrieving the data inserted, make sure that the array get populated with the image name, in your case the field is `image_name`. if its always the same path than you can put the path in the loop like I did above

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, I'd say that one of your issues may be that you need to enclose the location of the image:

```
$rows['image'] = 'url(http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/pictures?image_id=' . $rows['image_id'] . ')';
```

Give that a go.

Comment: hi! I tried what you have said above but i just got the whole url being displayed. Still not the image. but thanks anyway! if you have other opinion or suggestion please just tell me again. :)